# Can I control Minecraft Pi Edition over SSH from another computer?

Tags: python, ssh, minecraft

I recently downloaded the Minecraft Pi edition for my Raspberry Pi. The main feature of the Minecraft Pi edition is the ability to interactively edit the landscape using Python. One would expect that if you can control a game through Terminal on the Raspberry Pi, you should be able to control it through terminal over ssh. Is this possible?

Comment: In a word, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is entirely possible to control the Minecraft Pi edition interactively through ssh, with one caveat. To control Minecraft Pi edition, you must first launch Minecraft Pi edition. However, you can only launch it from the Raspberry Pi itself. Once it is launched, however, you will be able to control it through ssh. To do so, first ssh into your Raspberry Pi. Then navigate to the folder containing the Minecraft Pi edition. In this folder are a number of subfolders. You want to navigate to `api/python/`. Now launch Python in interactive mode, by typing `python`. To control Minecraft Pi edition, you must then type `import mcpi.minecraft as minecraft`. Now you can establish a connection to the game by typing `mc = minecraft.Minecraft.create()`. From this point you can issue commands by typing `mc`, followed by the command name. For example, `mc.postToChat("Hi")`.

Incidentally, you don't even need ssh in order to control Minecraft Pi edition remotely. If you download Minecraft Pi edition onto your regular PC, you can edit the API to connect to your Pi without ssh. To do this, navigate through `api/python/mcpi`, and open `python.py`. Now search for the word `localhost`, and replace it with the IP address of your Raspberry Pi. Now you can run code locally on your **regular** computer, and it will still communicate with Minecraft on the Pi. (Assuming Minecraft is running.)

Comment: I just tried Minecraft on the pi. I could start it over ssh, once I had said startx in another ssh session. This opened a black window on the pc where I ran ssh, and showed the Minecraft graphics on a TV connected to the raspberry. The black window then accepted both mouse and keyboard input, so I could play completely over ssh.

Comment: That is really cool!

Comment: @Frepa any idea how to play Minecraft over SSH *without* a TV?  My main goal is to be able to write Python scripts and see it control Minecraft, but all from my laptop...

Comment: @Dave do you mean you want the Minecraft graphics to render on your laptop screen, rather than on your Pi's screen?

Comment: @Dave : While presumably you can run an x client on your laptop, it's probably nicer just to set everything up on your laptop, without the Pi. You can either use a craftbukkit server with the Raspberry Juice mod, or using a Minecraft modded with my Raspberry Jam mod.

Comment: @Dave I'm really new to the PI but from what I've seen I think that Minecraft may write directly to the hardware (HDMI output)--I'm not sure you can make it work on a remote xwindows device.  There is a LCD screen that you can get for the PI that might also work.

Comment: @BillK I think you are correct. If you want to control regular PC Minecraft with Python, you need to get a modded server comparable with Bukkit or Spigot plugins, and install the Raspberry Juice plugin. It implements the same API as the Rasperry Pi Minecraft, so your code should still work.

Comment: You can now pass the IP address to the [**`Minecraft.create`**](https://github.com/brooksc/mcpipy/blob/master/mcpi/minecraft.py#L170) function.